# How do I get user email, name upon login in Web API C# backend?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I want to get the user email and name upon login. I noticed that if I create a custom provider I can see this information

```
// WebApiConfig.cs
options.LoginProviders.Remove(typeof(GoogleLoginProvider));
options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(CustomGoogleLoginProvider));


public class CustomGoogleLoginProvider : GoogleLoginProvider
{
    public CustomGoogleLoginProvider(HttpConfiguration config, IServiceTokenHandler tokenHandler)
        : base(config, tokenHandler)
    {

    }

    public override LoginResult CreateLoginResult(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, string secretKey)
    {
        // name and email are on the ClaimsIdentity
        var result = base.CreateLoginResult(claimsIdentity, secretKey);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I can see the info I want on the claims identity. But how do I access them in an API method? If I attempt to get Claims from User they are not the same. Are these claims returned to `CreateLoginResult` stored somewhere? Or can I store it for later use?

I think it might be stored in an ExternalIdentity, is that right? How do I access it?

I tried

```
var owin = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
var auth = owin.Authentication;

var user = auth.User;
var identity = auth.User.Identity;

var externalIdentity = auth.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

But `externalIdenity.Result` returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem I have is because I was assuming the claims were persisted. However it seems that the REST service does not keep any kind of open session, so all the values from one session will not be present in other requests.

What I have to do is store the information from login into the database and access when I want through the user id.

To accomplish that I can use the `Authenticated` method to get all external values I want and save it to the database.

```
public class CustomGoogleLoginProvider : GoogleLoginProvider
{
    public CustomGoogleLoginProvider(HttpConfiguration config, IServiceTokenHandler tokenHandler)
        : base(config, tokenHandler)
    {

    }

    public override void ConfigureMiddleware(IAppBuilder appBuilder, ServiceSettingsDictionary settings)
    {
        var options = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = settings["MS_GoogleClientID"],
            ClientSecret = settings["MS_GoogleClientSecret"],
            AuthenticationType = this.Name,
            Provider = new CustomGoogleLoginAuthenticationProvider()
        };

        appBuilder.UseGoogleAuthentication(options);
    }
}

public class CustomGoogleLoginAuthenticationProvider : GoogleLoginAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task Authenticated(GoogleOAuth2AuthenticatedContext context)
    {
        var result = base.Authenticated(context);

        var owin = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
        var auth = owin.Authentication;

        var identity = auth.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        //
        // store things I want in the database
        //

        return result;
    }
}
```